# Can't install Laravel Telescope in ubuntu 18

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-5.8

I am creating a new project in Laravel 5.8 and I also want to install Telescope, but when I execute the command in my project:

```
composer require laravel/telescope
```

output:

```
./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/telescope 2.0.x-dev requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - laravel/telescope v2.0 requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - laravel/telescope v2.0.1 requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - laravel/telescope v2.0.2 requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - laravel/telescope v2.0.3 requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - laravel/telescope v2.0.4 requires moontoast/math ^1.1 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - moontoast/math 1.1.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - moontoast/math 1.1.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - moontoast/math 1.1.0 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/telescope ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/telescope[2.0.x-dev, v2.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I install the missing dependencies? I'm working on PHP 7.2 and ubuntu 18.04.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to install the `bcmath` extension. In your case, it can be done by running

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath`

`sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath` if you have PHP 7.1

Then run the require command again.

Comment: `composer require "laravel/telescope":"~1.0"` worked for me. i am using Laravel v 5.7.11

Comment: If you still face that issue then you can load it by running 
sudo service apache2 restart